# how do I run a full video from a directory one after another video without skipping frames with python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming

I am writing a script that loops through a directory that has multiple videos of 2mb and reads them and displays them. the issue is it does read them but skips frames and for some videos, it just skips them giving an error that cannot read the frames. when I try running individual videos they work fine so the only issue is if I loop through them

I am trying to eventually build a script that takes videos and send them as post request to the server that can save them in the mongodb database but because I am new to this I am just trying to build it one piece at a time. if you guys can suggest anything that would be awesome

````
import os
import cv2 as cv
# import time

def get_video_duration(video_path):
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(video_path)
    fps = cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    frame_count = int(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    duration = frame_count / fps
    cap.release()
    return duration

folder_path = '/Users/api/ramses/video3/'  # Specify the folder containing video files
video_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.mp4')]

for video_file in video_files:
    video_path = os.path.join(folder_path, video_file)
    print("Processing video:", video_path)

    cap = cv.VideoCapture(video_path)

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # If frame is read correctly, ret is True
        if not ret:
            print(f"Can't receive frame from {video_file}. Moving to the next video...")
            break
        gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
    # time.sleep(17)
    cap.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

    

print("Finished displaying all videos.")```
````